# Приложения с правами администратора Android на Python

Tags: android, python

День добрый, возник вопрос. Вот я пишу небольшие программы на Python для андроид, знаю что можно получить более высокие права ( права администратора ) на приложение. К примеру их можно увидеть в разделе Администраторы устройст